# HQL Error : with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I am trying to run this query which will give me the count
but it does seem to work

```
def query  = "select count(A.id) from Artifact A "+
             "LEFT JOIN A.classification C on (A.id=C.artifactId) "+
             "where C.id IS NULL";
def tc = Artifact.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may help:

```
def query  = "select count(A.id) from Artifact A "+
             "LEFT JOIN A.classification C "+
             "where C.id IS NULL";
def tc = Artifact.executeQuery(query);
```

You don't need ON here because Artifact should already be "connected" with classification through mappings.